# The tag [product-recommendation] is misleading

Tags: discussion, tags

As with most SE sites, [the scope definition of our site](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) disallows pure "tell me what to buy" questions. Previous discussion:

- [To what extent are "recommend a solution" questions allowed](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/to-what-extent-are-recommend-a-solution-questions-allowed)
- [What should the help center read about on-topic and off-topic questions?](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/what-should-the-help-center-read-about-on-topic-and-off-topic-questions)

However, we currently have a tag named [product-recommendation](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-recommendation). This is misleading and should be fixed.

I'm intending to look at the questions in more detail and figure out a fix myself, so this meta post isn't a request for someone else to go fix it, but more putting it on the record that the problem exists. But if you have an opinion on good replacement tags, or in particular tags which are fit for the sorts of shopping-*related* questions we want to keep around, do weigh in.

Comment: Note that the only questions in that tag which really deal with product or service recommendations and are still open are from when the site was quite young and when we were still hashing out our topic scope. Those have probably been left open more by accident than intent, and *may* be candidates for closing as off-topic under the site's current topic scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the questions under that tag either (a) shouldn't have had that tag, or (b) deserved to be closed. I've removed the tag from the posts that fell under (a), and closed the ones that fell under (b).

Comment: Yep, guess that works. I've also removed the tag from the two closed questions, so that the tag will be deleted and thus not be suggested when asking questions — which was the root goal.